# Input field with dropdown Hints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-deployment, frontend

Hi I want to create an html input field with a hints menu. The effect should be like the image below. After clicking on the input field, the dropdown menu appears.

[image]

I wonder whether there are any plug-in or code example doing something similar?
Thank yoU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/H6eCp/)**</kbd>

```
<input type="text">

<div class="hints-menu">
  <span class="hints-title">Title 1</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 1</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 2</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 3</span>
  <span class="hints-title">Title 2</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 4</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 5</span>
  <span class="hints-title">Title 3</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 6</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 7</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 8</span>
  <span class="hint" title="Some title">Item 9</span>
</div>
```

---

```
input {
  width: 252px;
  height: 28px;
  padding: 0 4px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;

  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input:focus + .hints-menu {
  display: block;
}
.hints-menu {
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 240px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;

  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}
.hints-menu:before,
.hints-menu:after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 83%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.hints-menu:before {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  border-width: 9px;
  margin-left: -9px;
}
.hints-menu:after {
  border-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-width: 8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
}
.hints-title,
.hint {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #555;
}
.hints-title {
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.hint {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.hint:hover {
  color: #6fa024;
}
```

and for `.hint` title you can use [jQuery UI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: I've added jQuery UI Tooltip example in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/H6eCp/).

Comment: I am reading your code. and what does the "+" sign mean in the following code:  input:focus + .hints-menu {
    display: block;
}

Comment: `+` is used to select `.hints-menu` when input is focused. More about [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).